# Trilogy Sites Timeouts

Tags: support, 408-timeout

We are having connections issues with the Trilogy sites (and SE sites). Time outs, long waits for ajax calls etc. It usually works ok if I click things (links, buttons) twice or refresh.  But the first request almost always has random requests (js, css, ajax calls, etc..) that hang.

- This behavior is the same on *all* our workstations behind our firewall, so I am assuming our firewall is to blame.
- This has been the case for well over a year now, don't recall when it started. Could cope until now.
- The firewall is a [Clear OS](http://www.clearfoundation.com/Software/overview.html) box. Running the latest version, have upgraded/updated several times since this issue started. Have even replaced the hardware box with a fresh install.
- This behavior does not happen on other web sites. It is consistent on the Trilogy sites however.
- Running Firebug, shows the hang requests, but they are always random, and always 1 or 2 instances. Most of the time they do eventually return data, but after up to 2 minutes wait.

Any tips on continuing to troubleshoot this issue?

**Update** Here is FireBug's output of a typical request:
[image]

**Update 2** This has gotten worse. Sites are almost unusable. Gone through several firewall upgrades, changed ISPs. Upgraded browsers, still happens on all workstations on our LAN. Typical Firebug output:[image]

Comment: have been getting a similar issue (refer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125539/problems-when-pressing-accept-or-adding-comments) - I was surprised to see you're running clear os as I am too (Clear OS Enterprise verison 5.2).