# Problems when pressing "accept" or adding comments?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, ajax

I always have problems using StackOverflow from home for some reason. The issue is:

- Often clicking on an ACCEPT link, or an ADD COMMENT link may take a long time to work, or often not work at all after which StackOverflow provides an ERROR OCCURRED message back
- I have no problem with my internet connection for other sites
- I do note with stackoverflow the download indicator can stay spinning for a while (status bar seems to indicate in the last case still downloading something).   I'm guessing it's getting semi-stuck going back to download other Javascript bits perhaps(?)
- So it almost seems the issue is related to a website that uses ajax is my perception
- Don't seem to have a problem at work

Has anyone else had this problem?   Any advise?

*If it's not a stackoverflow issue, any advise on where I could seek help/advice on how to track down the issue.  I probably need some sort of tool to monitor times of http calls, including AJAX ones.  But once I track down a slow return then what, would need some non-browser based tool to simulate doing the same thing to see if it still occurs.  Anyway...*

EDIT 1 - Using Chrome tools I note that for this page when loading I get the following - i.e. this is the resource that takes a long time to load and then times out...

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel;r=103205753;a=p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc;fpan=0;fpa=P0-763725906-1327094619117;ns=0;ce=1;je=1;sr=1920x1080x24;enc=n;dst=0;et=1331722456052;tzo=-600;ref=;url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F125539%2Fproblems-when-pressing-accept-or-adding-comments%23comment338939_125539;ogl=".
__qc.firepixelquant.js:23
__qc.quantservequant.js:25
quantservequant.js:27
(anonymous function)quant.js:28

Unexpected response code: 502
full.js:7WebSocket closed
```

Comment: perhaps you are having connectivity issues with our CDN, we load the scripts at the bottom of the page now

Comment: I see this problem at work from time to time, though I don't know the cause. You can use your browser dev tools to diagnose the AJAX communication.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: using Chrome, but could switch to Firefox - why? were you thinking of a specific plugin for the browser that might be good for diagnostic?

Comment: @Greg - Diagnostics are built into Chrome. Press F12. You're looking for the Network tab.

Comment: ok - will have a look tonight

Comment: @waffles added some monitoring output in the post - does seem to be a quantserv set of resources that don't want to load...  is that a CDN issue then?

Comment: Might be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71154/trilogy-sites-timeouts

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - that's very interested as I actually am using a  Clear OS firewall here at home myself...

Comment: So try adding `127.0.0.1 pixel.quantserve.com` to your [HOSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file and hopefully it will sort things out for you as well. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've recently been noticing similar issues with things loading very slowly, but I'm pretty sure it's due to the web filter at work.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd to my Macbook hosts file I assume? (as opposed to firewall linux server?).  So will this block everything from pixel.quantserve.com?  Wondering how this would affect browsing on any other sites?

Comment: @Greg to the local file, yes.. this will indeed cause instant failure of any request instead of waiting and timing out and will cause your browsing to websites using [Quantcast Measurement](http://www.quantcast.com/) to not log your activity and not "count" you as a visitor. No big deal! :-)

Comment: I am the author of the question linked above. Unfortunately the HOSTS file pixel.quantserve.com did not actually fix it after further testing. I just forgot about that post, I have since deleted my "suggestion/answer". I'm still having these slowdowns. And yes still using Clear OS for our firewall.

Comment: I did try this and do some testing, but I now see there are other resources that occasionally get stuck/take a long time to respond.  In the recent test

Comment: @Greg Can you hit this site, and tell me if you get an exception: http://dwarffortresswiki.org

Comment: @Greg did you ever resolve this?